# Bit string functions

Tags: functions, bit-strings

I'm enrolled in a course of ML, and we were asked to provide a problem domain for a fitness functions over bit string where we have to find the value of X which maximize the output of the function.

The problem is that I really know nothing about bit string or bit string functions. Perhaps, If I know what are they exactly, I could complete my assignment.

I would appreciate any explanation with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit string is just a string of bits, of zeros and ones.  A bit string function is a function that takes a bit string and produces a result.  It might be the number of $1$s in the string, it might be the total length, it might be anything.  Fitness functions presumably return a result between $0$ and $1$ and can be thought of as the likelihood of survival of a set of genes.  It might be that certain positions reward $1$s and others reward $0$s.  There might be correlations, like position $2$ and $5$ should be the same for maximum fitness.